# Should I ask questions that are too easy to answer, like confirmations?

Tags: discussion

Let's say my question is really easy to answer and I mostly understand the sentence but just want confirmation, is the Japanese stack exchange an appropriate place to ask? If not, where could I ask such questions?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ask for a proofreading, then I'm afraid proofreading requests are off-topic on the site, so.. how about asking it on our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language) instead? :)